# MessageDialog ShowAsync Catastrophic Failure

Tags: c#, uwp

I try to update the MainPage UI with data received from a Serial port. Once the data is received, an event is raised, so I send a Message using MVVMLight to the MainPage hoping to update the UI with. What could be wrong here?

The following sample works just fine if I try to call the function from the Main constructor *or even when updating a simple TextBlock after the Serial event has been raised*.

```
private void OnMsgRecieved(PortMsg obj)
{
    ShowDialog(obj.StringID);
}

private async void ShowDialog(string msg)
{
    var dlg = new MessageDialog(msg);
    try
    {
      await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>
        {
          await dlg.ShowAsync();
        });
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
      // Catastrophic Failure
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the description, I think that this happens because you don't create `MessageDialog` on `UIThread`. Place it inside the Dispatcher and everything should be fine.

Other than that you may also check whether this is being called from some wrong context (e.g. from some page that is not shown anymore), but it is less likely to cause this problem.

Comment: Your first assumption is correct! But this is not an absolute case, or in other words, it does not apply to all variables declared outside the dispatcher while being used inside it. Any interpretation?!

Comment: @usefulBee it is the case for UI elements. You should create them inside the Dispatcher. Of course non-UI objects or variables like string can be created anywhere and used in Dispatcher.